# Native crash happened ~2k times but only affected 6 users with 3 specific Samsung devices

Tags: android, crash, native

Recently we have seen a very strange crash in our app. It's a native crash and we cannot reproduce it but only see it in the Play Store Android vitals.
It only happens on Samsung Galaxy S9+, Samsung Galaxy S9 and Samsung Galaxy Note8 and only on Android 8. More than 99% of the crashes happened on the S9+. The crash occurred almost 2k times since the last update of our app (in which we also updated some libs and dependencies) but only 6 users are affected.
Who would keep using the app if it crashes that often? We don't have any automated tests running on the affected devices. It almost feels like somebody is intentionally trying to harm our Play Store listing.
Has anybody ever experienced something similar?

The only useful piece of information we got in the back traces is this:
`/system/lib64/libutils.so (android::RefBase::incStrong(void const*) const+8)`